# Unable to call a servlet from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, error-handling

I am trying to call Servlet from JSP page.

**index.jsp:**

```
<a href="VisitServlet">Visit</a>
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
Web Page --> Pages --> HomePage --> index.jsp
Source Packages --> servlets.a.b.VisitServlet.java
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VisitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.a.b.VisitServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VisitServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VisitServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am getting **this error:**

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
```

Comment: try adding the web context e.g. myApp/VisitServlet

Comment: @ScaryWombat how to call servlet using web context?

Comment: <a href="VisitServlet">Visit</a> will construct a link with relative path. From the directory structure I assume that index.jsp will be accessible as http://<host>:<port>/<web app context>/HomePage/index.jsp, so the link would look like "http://<host>:<port>/<web app context>/HomePage/VisitServlet". Try using <a href="/VisitServlet">Visit</a> to build URL with absolute path.

Comment: What URL is being called from the browser when you click on the "Visit" link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/VisitServlet">Visit</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain `$` , why we use curly braces `{}` and `pageContext` ?

Comment: A JSP is nothing more than a servlet, so when using ${} you are accessing a JSP variable available in the pageContext Object, this pageContext object is one of the predefined JSP available vars from the Runtime API, so when you are rendering your page your anchor tag must point to the full path of your web app when accessing the servlet, otherwise it will resolve to a different URL.

Comment: I am still getting same error.. please check my post for error details.

Comment: can you do one thing? place this on your JSP: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and place here what is resulting string? Also can you post the Servlet class code ?